# How can i make like this table

Tags: tables, longtable, memoir, multirow, overleaf

[image]I want to make loke this table, but when I tried it's given me an error because the words in the declaration box appear off-page causing an error.

Comment: HI ! What did you do so far ? Please provide us a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| X | X |}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{| p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth} |}{\slshape\textbf{Declaration}: The project will be conducted in compliance with the University's Research
  Integrity Framework (P1415-956). This includes securing appropriate consent from
  participants, minimizing the potential for harm, and compliance with data-protection, safety
  \& other legal obligations. Any significant change in the purpose, design or conduct of the
  research will be reported to the SOM-REC Chair, and, if appropriate, a new request for
  ethical approval will be made to the SOM-REC.} \\
  \hline
  \textbf{Signature of PGT Student} & Date \\
  & \\
  \hline
  \textbf{Signature of Supervisor} & Date \\
  & \\
  \hline
  \textbf{Decision of Supervisor} & Approved or requires full ethical review \par (Delete as appropriate)  \\
  \hline
  \textbf{Decision of SOM-REC} & Date \\
  & \\
  \hline
  \textbf{Signature of SOM-REC Chair or SOM-REC Deputy Chair} & Date \\
  & \\
  \hline
  SOM-REC Reference Number (office use only) & \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```